# Webservices help

Tags: asp.net

We have a web service running on the server. We want to use the service in local machine. Could some one kindly give all the steps to get the methods availble in the client.

We have created web methods in the server. And trying to access the same thing on the client. I can literally access those methods using the refernce variable of the server. but when I try to run it , it comes up with run time exception unable to connect to remote server.

I have added the web reference to my client class. What else I am missing. Do I need to do any kind of registration of service with client  from command prompt.

I am assuming the client is unable to connect to server because the server is not running when I try to access the methods.

Any one with guidance will be helpful.
Thank you
Hari Gillala

I have added web refernce to this below client class using http://ipaddressofwerver/decisionclass/decisionclass.svc

The code:

```
try
    {
        DecisionClass ds = new  DecisionClass();

             string s = ds.Url;
        Label1.Text = s;
        string [] a = ds.GetList();
        foreach (string i in a)
        {
            Response.Write(i);


        }


    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Response.Write(Ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Posting some code might help clarify what you are looking for. Its unclear what the issue is or how to go about solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am assuming the client is unable to connect to server because the server is not running when I try to access the methods.

If it's not running, it won't generate a WSDL either. However, it may have been running while you created the web reference, and then stopped.

Here are some things you can try to track down the problem:

- Open the web service's URL, as specified in the web reference, in a regular web browser. This should bring up the web service's documentation page, and if you're running locally and haven't changed the web service's web.config, you can even call some simple methods using the provided test forms
- See if you can access the web service with SoapUI or a similar tool.

Also, make sure you're running the web service in IIS, not in the Visual Studio development server - IIS will keep running when you close the project or even Visual Studio, but the development server might not.

Comment: I tried to test it with the SoapUI 3.1.6 and still get the unable to connect to remote server error. So I literally don't know what is happening?

Comment: What does the web service you're calling do? Does the exception come from the web service client, or from the web service itself?